# Order of the word "chapter" and the chapter name

Tags: grammar, word-order

I see a lot of authors write something like below when refer to chapter or section in research publications:

> Refer to Methodology chapter,...
>
> We discuss the problem in the [Methodology chapter or Hypothesis
>   section] about...

Should we use "chapter Methodology" or "section Hypothesis"? or the above examples is correct because it is compound nouns?

For plural references, how about the following sentence?

> We discuss the problem in the chapters Introduction and Methodology...

or

> We discuss the problem in the Introduction and Methodology chapters...

Comment: Either "the Methodology chapter" or "the chapter on Methodology" (and there's a ticklish issue as to whether Methodology should be capitalized in that second case).

Answer (score 1):

The examples you cite are correct; your proposed alterations, not so. What is critical here is that the names of the sections and chapters are generic rather than proper. One could very well refer to the 33<sup>rd</sup> chapter in *Moby-Dick* as “the chapter ‘The Specksynder’ ” because that chapter title is (so far as I know!) unique to that novel; but for scientific research articles or theses to have sections or chapters headed or titled *Introduction, Hypothesis,* and *Methodology* is routine.